# What's the differences between HttpContext.Current.Items[] and HttpContext.Current.Request[]?

Tags: c#, .net

I really can't find out what is really the differences between these two methods in C#/.NET.

In fact they should do the same actions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first contains a safe read/write storage location that could be used throughtout the entire HTTP request. You could use it for example to store some object in the Begin_Request method and it will be available up until the page renders. It's like a Session but that lives only for the lifetime of a single HTTP request. You can access it from everywhere during during this request and it is specific to the context of the current request only.

The second is readonly storage for query string, POSTed form parameters, server variables and cookies.

Comment: The second also contains server variables and cookies. If possible use `Request.Form` or `Request.QueryString` to only get the specific data that you need.

Comment: @Guffa, yes, you are absolutely right. Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Items` is a NameValueCollection useful for storing and sharing data for the life of the HTTP Request.  The `Request` meanwhile provides access and methods specific to the HTTP Request.  Neither are methods however.